# How would one go about getting Apple to adjust the standard kerning table for a small obscure part of unicode

Tags: font

Playing around on facebook recently, I typed some old norse runes, and noticed that the kerning is positively atrocious. Not too surprising, since this is very much an edge case. Nonetheless, I would really want to have this fixed, and was wondering what it might take to actually succeed. I'm sure I could get the actual kerning table crowdsourced, but how would I go about getting Apple to incorporate it into the standard fonts?

Here's an example of my name: `ᛉᛅᚱᚴᚢᛋ`, as you can see, there is *way* too much space between the `ᛉ` (m) and the `ᛅ` (a).

Comment: Of course non-mac users viewing your text will be using different fonts.  Nothing Apple does will affect them.

Comment: Obviously, but *I* will see see the difference :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/problem/viewproblem) - it's really the only way to get their attention.